# Black screen after log-in on 13.04! I dont see an answer to me problem!

Tags: boot, login

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on on my Windows XP PC. I used a flash drive to install and wipe out Windows XP. After the installation completes I am able to log in but the screen is black/

I don't know anything about how to even get to the terminal so please write simple directions.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Ubuntu. Just use the flash drive to install it again. Make sure you select the option to erase any other operating system to that it's a clean install.